# Problem when saving plot from reactive inputs in R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny, save

I want to save plots in my R Shiny app but it doesn't work. I only have an empty file and i don't know how to fix it. This is a basic shiny construction, made step by step by following tutorials, so i think it should be easy for you to understand it.
Here is my code:

ui.R
'''

```
    ui <- navbarPage(

           navbarMenu("Times series",
                        tabPanel("Abiotiques",
                                  selectInput("Time_Series", p(strong("Which parameters do you want
                                  to plot as time serie?")), 
                                    choices = list("Temperature", "Salinity", "O2")),

                                  selectInput("Station", p(strong("Which station do you want to
                                                                  plot as time serie?")),
                                              choices = list("120","130","215","230","330",
                                                             "700","710","780","ZG02")),


                                  mainPanel(plotOutput("TS", height = 550),
                                            downloadButton("foo", "Download plot"))) 

                     )
```

'''

server.R

```
 shinyServer <-  function(input, output) {

selectDate <- reactive({
 switch(input$Station,
            "120" = filter(s120, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]),
            "130" = filter(s130, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]),
            "215" = filter(s215, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]),
            "230" = filter(s230, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]),
            "330" = filter(s330, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]),
            "700" = filter(s700, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]),
            "710" = filter(s710, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]),
            "780" = filter(s780, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]),
            "ZG02" = filter(sZG02, Time >=input$dateRangeTS[1] & Time<=input$dateRangeTS[2]))

                      })

output$TS <- renderPlot({ y <- switch(input$Time_Series, "Temperature" = ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = Temperature), ) + geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "Temperature") + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(0, 25),

        "Salinity" = ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = Salinite), ) +
          geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "SalinitÃ©") +
          scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(27, 37),

        "O2" = ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = `O2 (mg/L)`), ) +
          geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "O2") +
          scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(NA, 15))

          plot(y)
                  })

output$foo <- downloadHandler(
 filename = function() {
 paste("test", "png", sep=".")

 },

 content = function(file) {

 if(input$Time_Series == "Temperature")
   png(file)
   print(ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = Temperature), ) +
   geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "Temperature") +
   scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(0, 25))


 if(input$Time_Series == "Salinity")
   png(file)
   print(ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = Salinite), ) +
     geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "SalinitÃ©") +
     scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(27, 37))

 if(input$Time_Series == "O2")
   png(file)
   print(ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = `O2 (mg/L)`), ) +
     geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "O2") +
     scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(NA, 15))

 dev.off()

   }
  )
  }
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets after the `if` statements because right now you're only doing `png()` in the ifs. Also, try `ggsave()`:

```
output$foo <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste("test", "png", sep=".")

  },
  contentType = 'image/png',
  content = function(file) {

    if(input$Time_Series == "Temperature") {
      p <- ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = Temperature), ) +
        geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) +
        labs(x = "Time", y = "Temperature") +
        scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) +
        ylim(0, 25)
    } else if (input$Time_Series == "Salinity") {
      p <- ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = Salinite), ) +
        geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) +
        labs(x = "Time", y = "SalinitÃ©") +
        scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) +
        ylim(27, 37)
    } else if (input$Time_Series == "O2") {
      p <- ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = `O2 (mg/L)`), ) +
        geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "O2") +
        scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) +
        ylim(NA, 15)
    }

    if (exists('p')) {
      # ggsave() guesses it's png from the file extension
      ggsave(file, p)
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. When i click on "Download plot", it opens my directory but it saves the plot as "all files" and not .jpg, so i can't open it once saved. But i've finally replaced the function() by .pdf and it works without problem (in a pdf file obviously), just by modifying that. It's weird but i'm happy enough with pdf format! Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: There, I added the content type. I used png as you asked in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Do your plot in a reactive conductor, in this way you won't have to duplicate the code to save it:

```
myplot <- reactive({ 
  switch(input$Time_Series, 
        "Temperature" = ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = Temperature), ) + geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "Temperature") + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(0, 25),

        "Salinity" = ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = Salinite), ) +
          geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "SalinitÃ©") +
          scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(27, 37),

        "O2" = ggplot(data = selectDate(), aes(x = Time, y = `O2 (mg/L)`), ) +
          geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + labs(x = "Time", y = "O2") +
          scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) + ylim(NA, 15))
})

output$TS <- renderPlot({myplot()})
```

And use `ggsave`:

```
output$foo <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste("test", "png", sep=".")
  },

  content = function(file) {
    ggsave(file, myplot())
  }
)
```

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. When i click on "Download plot", it opens my directory but it saves the plot as "all files" and not .jpg, so i can't open it once saved. But i've finally replaced the function() by .pdf and it works without problem (in a pdf file obviously), just by modifying that. It's weird but i'm happy enough with pdf format! But thanks a lot for your tips about reactive conductor!